# Finding a particular element in a (large) set

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list, I want to remove all commas and just be left with the elements of the set.

```
Tuples[{I, l}, 16]

{{I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I}, {I, I, I, I, I, I, 
      I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, l}, {I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, 
      I, I, l, I}, {I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, l, l}, ....}
```

So what I want is something like:

```
{{IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII}, {IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIl}, {IIIIIIIIIIIIIIlI}, {IIIIIIIIIIIIIIll}, ....}
```

This above question was answered, however now I want to find a particular item in the above set, how must I proceed?

for example say I wanted to find the permutation

```
{IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI}
```

how must I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst =  (Symbol@*StringJoin /@ Tuples[{"I", "l"}, 16]);
Position[lst, IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI][[1, 1]]
```

> 315

```
lst[[315]]
```

> `IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI`

```
highlighted = MapAt[Style[#, Red, Bold] &, lst, {pos}];
highlighted[[300 ;; 360]]
```

[image]

Alterantively,

```
highlighted = st /. IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI -> Style[IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI, Bold, Red]
```

Comment: This is good but is there a way to pinpoint the desired element in the whole list? I mean, trying to locate position 315 out of 65000+ elements is quite difficult!

Comment: @A.E., can elaborate on "pinpoint" (and what "finding" `{IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI}`  means)?

Comment: so suppose we have {{IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII}, {IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIl}, {IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI} ,{IIIIIIIIIIIIIIlI}, {IIIIIIIIIIIIIIll}, ....} and I want to locate {IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI}. Now I want mathematica to show me where this element lies in the list

Comment: @AE,you mean you want to display  65000+ elements of `lst`with `{IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI}` marked/highlighted?

Comment: yes this is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @A.E., maybe  you can try something like `pos = Position[lst, {IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI}][[1, 1]];
MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, lst, {pos}]` or like `lst /. {IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI} -> Style[{IIIIIIIlIIlllIlI}, Bold, Red]`?

Comment: yes this is what I was looking for, thank you! however I must ask, is there a way to remove the braces of the elements "inside the set"? meaning I want { element 1, element 2, ....}